# Twilio Task Reservation is not returning reservation timeout

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

We are currently implementing a new Contact Centre using Twilio TaskRouter.

The desired functionality is:

Call the available worker via Task Assignment URL.
If the Reservation times out (Worker does not answer), Change Worker Activity to Offline.
We have successfully established this scenario but the problem we are facing is that, we do not get reservation.timeout event. Instead of timeout we get reservation.canceled event. However we do get reservation timeout when we accept task using Twilio Taskrouter JS.
We are using "conference" instruction on Task Assignment URL.

Comment: Can you explain what happens when you receive the task assignment callback right now?

Comment: When we receive task assignment callback, we return a JSON response of "conference" instruct, then Twilio dial agent into the conference. Till here it is working fine no issues at all. The problem we are getting is when agent does not answer the call. In this case we should receive reservation timeout event but we are getting reservation cancel event.

Comment: That seems like a bug as the documentation says it should timeout. It's likely best to contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact), describe what is happening as above, and they will be able to report to the product team or debug your account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You will get reservation.canceled event with the reason Task TTL Exceeded.
You can implement your condition on this reason.